# Relative module was not found in Vue.js when build project

Tags: vue.js

I have a project on Vue.js with Typescript and when I run dev server (prod build too) it returns error in console:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>    This relative module was not found:
>
> *./app.vue in ./src/main.ts

I alredy tried to checkout previous project commits, update global and local packages, clone and build project on other machines, delete and reinstall packages, delete package-lock.json, create new project via vue cli and add project files on new configuration - and nothing was changed. Same error. Very strange for me.

Here is my main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './app.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And here App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <header-component></header-component>
    <main id="content" class="content row">
      <transition name="fade">
        <router-view/>
      </transition>
    </main>
    <footer-component></footer-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import HeaderComponent from './components/header/header.component';
import FooterComponent from './components/footer/footer.component';

@Component({
  components: {
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/vue2-animate/dist/vue2-animate.min.css";
@import "./styles/main.scss";
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You have a spelling error, change `import App from './app.vue';` to `import App from './App.vue';`

Comment: @DerekPollard how did I miss your comment before? I spent hours trying to figure out my problem, and now I'm searching again so I can post to help others. I upgrading my tooling and somehow things became case-sensitive.

Comment: @user1447679 glad I could help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It was a spelling error. I changed

```
import App from './app.vue';
```

to

```
import App from './App.vue';
```

and it fix the error.
Thanx to [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2020002/derek) for help

Comment: In my case it was the great solution, basically I had a problem with this when running `vue-cli-service build --modern`.

Comment: Same here! My app worked flawlessly until I upgraded the tooling, and realized 3 hours later it adopted case-sensitivity! Make sure your import matches file system.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be, because your node_modules, is not at the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed your nuxt project using `Yarn` try deleting the node_modules and then installing using `npm i` instead. There are some hooks that will not be run by yarn when installing your dependencies for nuxt.